# Regex: nth occurrence of a string

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to get the 3rd string between the 3rd and 4th occurrence of the / character using regex

the list of strings is something like this:

```
...
/restaurants/garnish/گارنیش/
/restaurants/burger1358/برگر-۱۳۵۸/
/restaurants/delion-saadat/صبحانه--و-میان-وعده-دلیون-شعبه-سعادت-آباد/
/restaurants/kamran/کامران--اسکای-فال-سابق-/
...
```

the desired output for the list above is something like this:

```
...
گارنیش
برگر-۱۳۵۸
صبحانه--و-میان-وعده-دلیون-شعبه-سعادت-آباد
کامران--اسکای-فال-سابق-
...
```

as the desired part of the string is not ASCII (English) and there is no pattern (names being different), I cannot figure out the proper regex syntax.

Comment: Use `str.split` instead.  `your_string.split('/')[2]` should be the string you want.

Comment: @PatrickHaugh well, I didn't think about it. thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the structure doesn't change, use `str.split`. In case the structure of the url changes and you only want to get the Persian characters, you can use the range of unicode characters for Persian to get the result you want.

```
import re 
line = "/restaurants/garnish/گارنیش/"

re.findall("([\u0600-\u06FF\s]+)", line)
['گارنیش']
```

Edit: if you want to find for every url in your list, the following is what you need:

```
lines = ['/restaurants/garnish/گارنیش/',
 '/restaurants/burger1358/برگر-۱۳۵۸/',
 '/restaurants/delion-saadat/صبحانه--و-میان-وعده-دلیون-شعبه-سعادت-آباد/',
 '/restaurants/kamran/کامران--اسکای-فال-سابق-/']
[''.join(re.findall("([\u0600-\u06FF\s]+)", n)) for n in lines]

['گارنیش','برگر۱۳۵۸','صبحانهومیانوعدهدلیونشعبهسعادتآباد','کامراناسکایفالسابق']
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible regex would be:

```
/.+?/.+?/(.+?)/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zEte2I/1)

---

However, as pointed out in the comments, you shouldn't use a regex for something that simple, it's overkill and not very performant (and also less readable). You should use [str.split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
 your_string.split('/')[3]
```

Comment: thank you for the response. Performance wise I thought regex would be a faster solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably dont need regexp for this

```
res = [w.split('/', 4)[3] for w in s.splitlines() if '/' in w]
```